# Why is inverse - sampling inefficient?

Tags: importance-sampling

One metric used to measure the efficiency of sampling in monte carlo sampling (given a dataset of size $n$) is the effective sample size $N_{eff}$.

*The efficiency of a sampling procedure depends partly in the effective sample size ESS for a raw set of N samples. The ESS is denoted by $N_{eff}$.

- In inverse transform sampling: all samples are direct samples from the target distribution so $N_{eff} = N$ (hence, the sampling process is inefficient)
  -In rejection sampling, the raw set of samples are from the proposal distribution but $N_{eff}$ is explicit - it is simply the number of accepted samples.
- In importance sampling, the ESS is $N_{eff} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i}^{N}w_{i}^{2}}$*.

I struggle to understand the above. A sequence $S$ of $N$ samples with correlation between the sample leads to redundancies so that the sequence $S$ would have an effective size less than $N$.

Shouldn't this imply then that inverse sampling is efficient?

Edit: to provide more context.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The statement is quoted from a set of lecture notes.

Comment: For example, how is this efficiency defined in your lecture notes?

Comment: What sort of sampling are we talking about? Sampling as in the use of a random number generator, or sampling as in performing some measurements in an experiment or sampling a population?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I have threw into the OP all there is on the notes.

Comment: What are the $w_i$? Can you imagine $N_{eff} = \frac{1}{\sum_{i}^{N}w_{i}^{2}}>N$ given what is stated in the rest of your lecture notes? Can importance sampling improve the result for the same amount of samples?

Comment: Possibly useful is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165168416302110

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04129 for the drawbacks of using effective sample size, incl. the fact that $N_\text{eff}<N$ except for exact (and not only inverse) sampling.